# Process/reduce the size of external images linked in WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, technical-seo

In my current project, we're creating block codes in WordPress automatically from Airtable data.
We use Airtable due to the ease of uploading/collecting image assets from our client (not that tech-savvy).

However, the images they're uploading are way too big, affecting our load times greatly.

I would like to keep using Airtable in order to avoid individually uploading to the WP Media Library (my plan B), but I wonder if you know any way to optimize the external images automatically to improve the load times and SEO.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Cloudflare Image Optimization.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/

> With Image Resizing, you can transform images on Cloudflare’s edge
> platform. You can resize, adjust quality, and convert images to WebP
> or AVIF format on demand. Cloudflare will automatically cache every
> derived image at the edge, so you only need to store one original
> image at your origin.
>
> Cloudflare Image Resizing lets you:
>
> Quickly and easily adapt images to your site’s layout and your
> visitors’ screen sizes without maintaining a server-side image
> processing pipeline on your servers. Integrate image processing with
> Workers , which enables advanced integrations such as custom URL
> schemes, content negotiation, and responsive images based on Client
> Hints.